Run GlueJobOperator with parameters based on dag run parameter
My Airflow dags has multiple variables as run params.
I would like to launch a Glue job with specific parameters based on one of the run params:
when run_type=0 I would like to launch the job with 2 workers standard type.
Otherwise I would like  to launch the job with 10 workers G.2X type.
This is what I done:
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.models.param import Param
from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import GlueJobOperator


run_type = '{{ params.run_type }}'


def determine_glue_config(task_instance: TaskInstance, **kwargs) -> None:
    """Determine Glue job configuration based on the run_type."""
    print(run_type)
    if int(run_type) == 0:
        confs = {
            "NumberOfWorkers": 2,
            "WorkerType": "Standard",
        }
    else:
        confs = {
            "NumberOfWorkers": 10,
            "WorkerType": "G.2X",
        }
    task_instance.xcom_push(key='glue_confs', value=confs)


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': '${alerting_email}',
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'executor_config': {
        'KubernetesExecutor': {'service_account_name': '${airflow_worker}', 'namespace': '${namespace}'}
    },
}


@dag(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Pipeline for Perfmarket ETL',
    tags=['perfmarket'],
    schedule_interval='${dag_scheduling_time}',
    start_date=datetime(2024, 10, 22),
    catchup=False,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
    concurrency=20,
    max_active_runs=20,
    params={
        'run_type': Param(default=0, type='integer'),  # Default to '0' (daily) if not specified,
        'start_date': Param(default=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'), type='string'),
        'end_date': Param(default=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'), type='string'),
    },
)
def perfmarket_dag() -> None:
    """Build the performance marketing dag."""
    start_task = EmptyOperator(task_id='start')

    generate_args_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="determine_glue_config",
            python_callable=determine_glue_config,
        )

    glue_bronze_task = GlueJobOperator(
        task_id='submit_bronze_glue_job',
        job_name=f'perfmarket-{environment}-wizaly-bronze-compute',
        wait_for_completion=True,
        script_location=f's3://{wizaly_project_bucket_name}/glue/bootstrap/perfmarket_bronze.py',
        s3_bucket=wizaly_project_bucket_name,
        stop_job_run_on_kill=True,
        run_job_kwargs="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='determine_glue_config', key='glue_confs') }}",
        script_args={
            '--S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME': wizaly_bucket_name,
            '--S3_IDT_ACCESS_ROLE_ARN': wizaly_bucket_role_access_arn,
            '--S3_MIROR_BUCKET_NAME': miror_bucket_name,
           '--S3_STAGING_BUCKET_NAME': wizaly_bucket_name,
            '--S3_WIZALY_BUCKET_NAME': wizaly_project_bucket_name,
            '--RUN_TYPE': f'"{run_type}"',
            '--START_DATE': f'"{start_date}"',
            '--END_DATE': f'"{end_date}"',
        },
    )

determine_glue_config >> glue_bronze_task

This fails with
[2024-12-10, 11:25:11 CET] {standard_task_runner.py:110} ERROR - Failed to execute job 10315 for task determine_glue_config (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{{ params.run_type }}'; 49)

